# Alternatives to YUMI

Tags: boot, bootable

Could anybody suggest an alternative to [YUMI](http://www.pendrivelinux.com/yumi-multiboot-usb-creator/)?

I have an entire folder dedicated to Linux distros and fix-it tools, so what I'm trying to do is find a different menu so that I can **boot several different ISOs from  from my HDD.**

This is exactly what YUMI does, and while I do like YUMI, there's always room to try something else.

(Preferably software that is *out* of beta.)